# How can I get a theme parent id from a theme id?

Tags: android, themes, android-theme, android-styles

In the following code I retrieve the theme id/name for the application. Is there a way to then use this to get the style parent?

```
val context = [ApplicationContext].getContext()
val packageName = context.packageName
val packageInfo = context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
val theme = packageInfo.applicationInfo.theme

val themeResourceEntryName = context.resources.getResourceEntryName(theme)
```

To clarify, my theme name might be "someTheme", but I'm interested in what is being extended - AppCompat or MaterialComponents, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get theme parent class using

```
Theme myThemeParent = appContext.getTheme().getClass().getSuperclass();
```

The code is in java, but I think you will have no problem rewriting it in kotlin

Comment: ```val myThemeParent: Class<in Resources.Theme>? = [ApplicationContext].theme.javaClass.superclass``` returns java.lang.Object. Am I missing something?

Comment: And if you bring to Theme. Will there be no mistakes?

Comment: it doesn't allow me to cast directly to Theme, only to Class<in Resources.Theme>